# Access perforce command line from P4V

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to run P4 command line from P4V? I understand that it can be done MS command prompt. But want to know, if it can be invoked via P4v?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Helix sadly removed the input textbox in 2017.3.

Comment: But you can right click on a folder in the depot view, then "Open command Windows Here".
It will open a cmd with correct p4 set config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see View > Log and in the bottom you can run p4 commands

[image]

Comment: That is not editable for me. Is there any specific setting I need to enable?

Comment: What is not editable? Log content or the input line box below? Note the region where the cursor is. (My version is Rev. P4V/NTX64/2017.2/1535556)

Comment: That was snuck in fairly late in the game (I think I added it in 2016.1? I forget now). But as Bartek mentions, it's not the log pane itself, it's an unmarked text edit BELOW the log pane. Any command you run there will run as if it were in the shell (even non-p4 commands unless someone broke it). It will also run as if it's the current workspace's environment. You can pass flags though just as if it were command line to change enviro though. So, e.g. p4 -u foo -c bar will run the command as user foo with client bar even if P4V is using a different connection.

Comment: I am running P4V version 2022.2, and I don't have a command line box at the bottom of my Log pane. There is just an uneditable status bar below my log pane.